# PHP not showing a value of a query when it contains double quotes and appears inside a hyperlink

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink, double-quotes

I am sending a simple query to mysql to get two fields and echo them to a table:

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT `Data`, `Cerca` FROM `llengua-cerques` ORDER BY `llengua-cerques`.`Data` DESC LIMIT 10;" ; }

$result = mysqli_query($app_db, $sql);
while ($aRow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

cerca = $aRow['Cerca'];
$cerca = stripslashes($cerca); ?>

<li><a href="/llengua/resultats.php?cerca=<?php echo $cerca; ?>"><strong><?php echo strftime( '%d/%m/%y', strtotime( $aRow['Data'] ) ); ?></strong><?php echo $cerca; } ?></a></li>
```

It is working fine, but this code  when:

- it contains a double quote (") AND
- is appears inside a link

it shows empty.

I can't solve it...

Comment: what if you try this syntax in href link
`<li><a href="/llengua/resultats.php?cerca={$cerca}"><strong><?php echo strftime( '%d/%m/%y', strtotime( $aRow['Data'] ) ); ?></strong><?php echo $cerca; } ?></a></li>`

Comment: Can you give a sample of a raw value for `cerca` which is not showing?

Comment: @HamidAli The output is: /resultats.php?cerca={$cerca} No value is echoed...

Comment: @El_Vanja Yes: "a pesar" (including quotes). Values with simple quotes are shown, and in mysql there no scape character.

Comment: If there are no escape characters in the raw value, then you don't need `stripslashes`. You should put `urlencode` around your variable in the `href` attribute. The reason is that unescaped double quotes in your value close the double quotes of the `href`.

Comment: @El_Vanja It works fine with `<?php echo urlencode($aRow['Cerca']); ?>`